# Keep getting error "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to create a custom dataset for a StyleGan project as instructed on the following video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=QBUFrep8ljI

But when I run the command to construct the data set

```
python dataset_tool.py create_from_images datasets/custom_dataset ./chrimg
```

I get the following error:

```
File "dataset_tool.py", line 18, in <module>
import numpy as np
  File "F:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
from . import _distributor_init
   File "F:\Program Files\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "F:\Program Files\Python3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Every step of the way I run into some new error, and I've managed to figure them out, but I have no clue on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that file has bad EXE format. In Windows OS files (such as exe,dll,sys) have PE format  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format
In your case, Python code tries to load DLL in this line of code:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

I believe that _dlopen uses LoadLibrary from Windows API internally which generates this error and there is the following possible reason for that:

1. dll file is tried to be loaded by LoadLibrary is corrupted
2. dll file and phython have different architectures (for example you
   python is x86 and dll is x64). You can figure out what exactly files are in game by using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) utility. Also, you can use [sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) to determine architecture or this method - https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows

Comment: So it would be my version of python?